# how can a bash file run without needing to enter sudo pass-phrase manually?

Tags: bash, sudo

I write a bash file thus:

```
#!/bin/bash         
echo 1000 |sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

(that changes the screen's brightness)

I need it to run at startup, but because it requires the sudo pass-phrase I must enter the pass-phrase manually. How can I reform this code not to require the sudo pass-phrase at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular problem, you could probably just stick `echo 1000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` in `/etc/rc.local` (before the `exit`-line). That would run it on boot, as root before the desktop was loaded.

But in general (how do I run a script as root?) things are a bit sticker...

You could just run `sudo ./myscript` (by editing `sudoers`) but just allowing `./myscript` to be run without a password would mean you (or a program running as you) could edit that file and suddenly you can run *anything* as root without going through the proper procedures. Uber-poor security.

Instead I would suggest:

```
sudo mv myscript /sbin/myscript
sudo chown root:root /sbin/myscript
sudo chmod 700 /sbin/myscript
```

The `ch*` commands now mean only root can read/run the script. Sticking it in `/sbin/` is just incidental - you don't have to do that.

Now you need to edit `/etc/sudoers`. [The Wiki has a good example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Shutting_Down_From_The_Console_Without_A_Password) and you'll just need to substitute the shutdown commands with your script's path (use a full, absolute path). `NOPASSWD` is the key keyword here. It allows you to run something as sudo without the password. So then you can just add `sudo /sbin/myscript` to your startup jibberyboo and you're flying.

Comment: Oli  what can you say about a solution like `echo password | sudo -S ./myscript` ?

Comment: @desgua Yuck. That would have your sudo-capable password in plaintext somewhere in your local settings/xinit. Essentially anything you ran could read it. You might as well stick your password in `~/heres-my-password-guys` in case somebody wants to root your computer :) The point of sudoers is to lock things down as far as you possibly can. My suggestion that limits that open access to a file that only somebody with legitimate root access could have written, without giving away your password or open root access.

Comment: For the record here is another reference that may be useful for someone viewing this page: http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html#nopasswd_and_passwd

Answer (score -3):

I'm just taking a shot in the dark, but try to change permissions on the file

> chmod 777 [file path]

Comment: That just means anybody and everybody can read/write/execute. It doesn't do anything for permissions.